# Obtain lengths of vectors without loading multiple .npy files

Tags: python, file, numpy

I have around 2000 .npy files, each representing a 1-dimensional vector of floats with between 100,000 and 1,000,000 entries (both of these numbers will substantially grow in the future). For each file, I would like the length of the vector it contains. The following option would be possible but time consuming:

`lengths = [numpy.shape(numpy.load(whatever))[0] for whatever in os.listdir(some_dir)]`

**Question:**  
What is the most efficient/fastest way to derive this list of vector lengths? Surely I should be able to work directly from the filesizes- but what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using memmapped files will speed this up considerably.
By memmapping the file numpy only loads the header to get array shapes and datatype, while the actual array data is left on disk until needed.

```
import numpy as np 
# Load files using memmap
data = [np.load(f, mmap_mode='r')) for f in os.listdir(some_dir)]
# Checking your assumptions never hurts
assert (d.ndim == 1 for d in data).all()  

lengths = [d.shape[0] for d in data]
```

**edit** The reason you need to load the file headers rather than using file size directly is that the header for `npy` files is not necessarily a fixed length.  Although for a single dimensional array without fields or fieldnames it probably won't change (see https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html).

Answer (score 2):

you probably can try this

```
import os

fileinfo = os.stats('1darray.npy')
```

**array length**

```
a = os.stat('1darray.npy')
int((a.st_size - 128)/itemsize)
```

128 is the extra size npy file takes when saved in a directory in the OS. the actual size in bytes of any any numpy array can be found as array.nbytes. So `a.st_size - 128 = array.nbytes`  and `array.bytes/array.itemsize = array.size = array lenght`

Where `itemsize = 2` if array is of type `float 16` bit, `4` if type is float `32` bit and `8` if array if of type `float 64` bit

## Here is a demo

```
import numpy as np
import os
array = np.arange(12, dtype=np.float64)
print(a.itemsize) # >> gives 8 for float 64 bit
np.save('1darray.npy', array)
a = os.stat('1darray.npy')
length = int((a.st_size - 128)/8) # >> gives 12 which is equal to array.size
```

so you have to know what is the `dtype` of saved numpy `npy` files

Therefore, for your case you might do this

```
lengths = [(os.stat(whatever).st_size - 128)/8 for whatever in os.listdir(some_dir)]
```

assuming dtypes of npy arrays is `float64`

Comment: What is the number 128 and how stable is it? (e.g. across numpy versions)

Comment: This is an extra size file file takes in addition to the original numpy array when saved in the operating system directory. you can check the size of any numpy array using nbytes, for example, if a is a numpy array a.nbytes gives its size. @DanielMoskovich

Comment: It's documented here (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html) , technically 128 is variable, bytes 9 & 10 in the header specify the size, which will always be padded such that the total size of the header is divisible by 64. Which appears to yield 128 in most practical applications.